# single default argument in a scala method

Tags: scala

If I define a method with a single argument with a default value, can I call it without passing any arguments?

```
scala> def printArgs(str:String = "default"){println(str)}
printArgs: (str: String)Unit

scala> printArgs
<console>:11: error: missing arguments for method printArgs in object $iw;
follow this method with '_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              printArgs
              ^
```

Comment: you must add a blank parens () though in this case so it should be `printArgs()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call it without any parameters, but you cannot call it without any parameter blocks--you need at least an empty list of arguments:

```
scala> printArgs()
default
```